# Array for all objects without a parent in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models. Hotels and Maps. Each **Hotel** has_one **Map**. I deleted a number of hotels before I implemented:

```
has_one :map, :dependent => :destroy
```

Now I need to find all the Maps where the hotel has been deleted and destroy them, possibly through the console? The Map is created at the same time as the Hotel so the ID will remain even once it has been removed.

Comment: May be from console, run these queries `hotel_ids = Hotel.pluck(:id)` and `Map.where.not(hotel_id: :hotel_ids).destroy`

Answer (score 2):

```
map_ids_to_check = Hotel.pluck(:map_id).uniq
maps_to_delete = map_ids_to_check.select {|map_id_to_check| not Map.exists?(map_id_to_check)}

maps_to_delete.each do |map|
  map.delete
end
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in console:

```
hotel_ids = Hotel.pluck(:id) # collect all available hotels ids
maps = Map.where.not("hotel_id IN (?)", hotel_ids)
maps.destroy_all
```

**OR**

```
hotel_ids = Hotel.pluck(:id) # collect all available hotels ids
maps = Map.where("hotel_id NOT IN (?)", hotel_ids)
maps.destroy_all
```

Comment: This will not work, as the Map is created at the same time as the Hotel.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner : Sorry I misunderstood.. let me update my answer

Comment: The query returns no results.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner : I have update the answer now please check

Comment: Still nothing. One example for you here: I have a hotel that has been deleted with the ID of 883. When I do Hotel.pluck(:id) 883 is not inside the array. Then I run the next query and there's no results.

Comment: @ItsJoeTurner : On Which Rails version you are working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83527/discussion-between-itsjoeturner-and-gagan-gami).

Answer (score 0):

just do it in sql and move on

```
delete from maps where not exists (select * from hotels where hotels.map_id = maps.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure SQL solution:

```
DELETE FROM maps WHERE hotel_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM hotels);
```